# How to export sparklyr (Spark ML) models to PMML?

Tags: r, scala, apache-spark, sparklyr

I know that **Spark ML pipelines** can be exported to **PMML** using the JPMML-SparkML library. I am just struggling to find out how I could do it from **R** using **sparklyr**.

I am aware of open github issue, where two ideas were raised:

- using Scala API, something like:

  ```
  model <- ml_kmeans(<...>)    
  sparkapi::invoke(model$.model, "toPMML", "./myModelPMML.xml")
  ```
- leverage https://github.com/jpmml/jpmml-converter
  and the https://github.com/jpmml/jpmml-sparkml

However I could not find any follow ups on that tips.
Has anyone tried any of these solutions?

[Here](https://github.com/rstudio/sparklyr/issues/60) is the related github issue to this question.

Comment: You'll need to wait for the answer of sparklyr on github I guess since you asked the question there an hour ago. I don't believe it's possible for the time being.

Comment: Yes, I posted a question on github as well. I am just checking here if anyone tried any workarounds.

Comment: I personally tried to find one. There is some limitations with sparklyr itself.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`sparklyr2pmml`](https://github.com/jpmml/sparklyr2pmml) package to export Sparklyr/Apache Spark ML pipelines to PMML.