# How to export a sparkR model as PMML?

Tags: sparkr, pmml

I'm trying to export a sparkR model as PMML.

The first approach was using the pmml library:

```
library(pmml)
sparkR.session()
data(iris)
df <- createDataFrame(iris)
model <- spark.kmeans(df, Sepal_Length ~ Sepal_Width, k = 4, initMode = "random")
model_pmml <- pmml(model)
```

The error:

```
Error in UseMethod("pmml"): no applicable method for 'pmml' applied to an object of class "KMeansModel"
Traceback:

1. pmml(model)
```

I also investigated if the `toPMML` method available on scala models could be used from SparkR.  I've found a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44702031/how-to-export-sparklyr-spark-ml-models-to-pmml) that suggests it may be possible with Sparklyr, but not with SparkR.

Any ideas?

Comment: I don't think SparkR API supports conversion to PMML as of now

Comment: I've created a jira to request this: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-21430

Comment: Should help if this get solved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have come to the conclusion that exporting a spark R model is not supported.  I have added a feature request for this: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-21430.  Please vote on the jira ticket if you are also looking for this functionality.